# Documents in lists not editable

Tags: list, document-library

Maybe someone can help me with a difficult problem.

I have SP farm with the latest version of SP (14.0.6120.5000) and everu document in every list in every web application as a problem.

After the first edit I cannot edit again (without a new session).

No discernible error exists in the logs.

Example: 
- new browser session 
- choose a word doc and edit in word
- save the doc
- open the doc again for edit
- it stays not editable and when i choose to edit in word it says it cannot find the file.

Does anybody ever seen this type of situation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem.

One of our custom webparts was publishing a service to the ISAPI folder, and that was overwriting the web.config there.

The actual problem was the service call CellStorage (defined in that web.config) that no longer existed.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the alternate access mappings. Although this does sound like a very bizarre problem.  I am assuming you are opening in IE 7 or above.

Comment: We have about 10 Web Apps on the farm, and another test farm with different mappings (public, private). And I even created three vanila web apps with the different auth options to test, and the result is the same in every one. Yes testing in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I would run fiddler to try to determine the issue.  If you post the trace results then I can take a look and see if anything looks funny.